# Using sed on a long line including conditions keywords and specific characters

Tags: linux, bash, sed, operator-keyword

I have that line in my .bash_profile file :

`if [ -f ~/.bash_profile.tomcat_8.5 ]; then . ~/.bash_profile.tomcat_8.5; fi`

And I would like to replace the whole line with

`if [ -f ~/.bash_profile.tomcat ]; then . ~/.bash_profile.tomcat; fi`

I had a hard time with all the /, then I learnt checking this site you could use any delimiter with sed, which is quite handy. But still, I cannot do what I want.

Here what I tried, using a + delimiter :

```
sed -i "s+if [ -f ~/.bash_profile.tomcat_8.5 ]; then . ~/.bash_profile.tomcat_8.5; fi+if [ -f ~/.bash_profile.tomcat ]; then . ~/.bash_profile.tomcat; fi+" /tmp/.bash_profile
```

I even tried using variables :

```
Delete='if [ -f ~/.bash_profile.tomcat_8.5 ]; then . ~/.bash_profile.tomcat_8.5; fi'

Add='if [ -f ~/.bash_profile.tomcat ]; then . ~/.bash_profile.tomcat; fi'

sed -i "s+$Delete+$Add+g" /tmp/.bash_profile
```

I've tried with {} around the variables, with single quote, double quote.
I wonder if this is a basic problem I can't solve because I am missing something easy, or if it's Something deeper because of all the specific keywords / characters.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[` `]` have special meaning in regular expressions (and also `.` and in extended regular expression also `+`, but that doesn't affect here). Read about [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). Escape special characters with backslash.

Do:

```
sed 's!something \[ something \] something\.something!!'
```

Comment: I thought only variables would go through single or double quote. I feel ashamed now, but I learnt something. Thanks for your quick answer !